# IDE Expert ‘go to implementations’ on an interface (like ReSharpers ‘GotoImplementations’)

Tags: delphi, ide, rad-studio

ReShaper has a command GotoImplementations, which enables you to jump to implementations of an interface (or a baseclass). Is there an IDE expert (IDE AddOn) that does the same?

Comment: I don't know any, sorry. Should be possible with extended RTTI, I guess. But be aware that you risk getting your question closed, because in effect, you are asking for a recommendation, and that is off-topic here.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What does RTTI have to do with code navigation in the IDE?

Comment: Can't ask for tool recommendations here according to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your future experiences here will be greatly improved if you spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to familiarize yourself with the site before posting.

Comment: @Stefan: is that only for code in the IDE? OK, then not with RTTI. Then it involves a little more, I guess.

Comment: @stefan I’m looking forward to hear you speak in Denmark next month about e.g. dependecy injections.  And that was actually the reason I asked for tools to debug/investigate code with wife use of interfaces and DI

Comment: Most likely there are no such. Try explore cnpack or you can write your own using [DelphiAST](https://github.com/RomanYankovsky/DelphiAST)